# How to detect trace file rolling on log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, trace, log4net-appender

I am using C# 4.6.1.

Let's assume I have successfully configured a log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, which will roll to a new trace file after a certain time or when the trace reaches a certain size threshold.

What I want to do now is to detect every time there is a file roll, because I need to do a certain operation with the full trace file that was just rolled, which is out of the scope of the question (I basically need to zip it, copy it to a certain folder and raise an event).

Is there a way to configure log4net to raise an event or execute a specific method when it is rolling to a new trace file?

Answer (score 0):

The log4net framework does not have out-of-the-box support for that or any configuration you can tweak to get it.

You need to implement your own custom appender class that inherits from `RollingFileAppender` and override its methods to suite your needs. The methods that more likely be of your interest are `Append`, `DoAppend`, `RollFile` and the `RollOver...` methods.

For more info check the [reference](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender.htm).